# Loading Facebook pixel async

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm loading the Facebook pixel and getting an error because the script isn't loaded when the call is made. This is what it looks like:

```
function Load3rdPartyScripts() {

    (function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js', undefined, undefined, undefined);

    fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'); //problem here
    fbq('track', 'PageView');

}
```

Problem is that fbq isn't initiated when the code runs. Now I know I could wrap the problem code inside a `setInterval` and keep checking until the external script is fully loaded but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this problem but in vain. Your code works perfectly.
`fbq` is appended syncronously (So no need to `timeout`) to `window` and will be called normally. Check yourself:

```js
(function Load3rdPartyScripts() {

    (function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js', undefined, undefined, undefined);

    fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // No problem here!
    fbq('track', 'PageView');

})();
```

### **But**

There are some potential reasons that may produce your error:

1. Running the script outside the browser, An env that ruined the window variable.
2. Running code on browser but with a freezed `window` (`Object.freeze(window)`) causes that `fbq` will be `undefined`
3. So also `Object.seal(window)` like `freeze()`. It will prevent new properties from being added to `window`
4. Creating a **local** scope **named** `window` variable will cause `fbq` to be `undefined`

   ```
   function Load3rdPartyScripts() {
       let window = {};  // Notice!
       (function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
           if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
               n.callMethod ?
               n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
           }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
           n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
           t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
       })(window, document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js', undefined, undefined, undefined);

       fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'); //problem here
       fbq('track', 'PageView');

   }
   Load3rdPartyScripts();
   ```

Comment: Duh, thanks for looking at my code, it was mistake 4 and fbq wasn't in the global scope. Thanks!!