# Is my Facebook pixel asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

My link shortener fires a Facebook pixel and sometimes it seems to slow down the redirect tediously. I wasn't able to find any documentation on whether Facebook pixels run sync or async and how to control it. There is a weird part of the code like this `t.async=!0;` but I am not sure what it means. Can anyone advise please?

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '649099668832642');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=649099668832642&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading Facebook pixel async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873285/loading-facebook-pixel-async)

Comment: I don't think so. At least not very clearly. I'd like to keep this one open as I think it's sufficiently distinct.